# Magnetic lines of force

Tags: magnetic-flux

Question:
If two, one-inch magnets with the same “pull” strength are magnetically connected to each other, do the combined magnetic lines of force extend twice as far as if only one magnet’s line of force was measured?

Comment: I think this belongs on the physics SE page, not here.

Comment: Magnetic lines of force extend to infinity but reduce, beyond a certain point with distance cubed.

Answer (score 2):

That rather depends on what you mean by magnetically connected to each.

[image]

If you mean end to end then other than being stretched by the cumulative addition of the extra magnet the "size" of the geometry of the field remains the same, extending to infinity and decaying in strength by \$R^3\$. However, with two magnets the field is almost doubled in intensity so it may seem it has a better pull at a certain distance.

[image]

If the magnets are coupled in parallel N-S as shown above, then the Distance between poles is significantly reduced and the magnetic field is effectively truncated close to the poles. In this scenario you actually have two spherical fields, one at each end, that decays quickly as you move away from the end.